# What is the 'this' object passed to an ng-click function call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this plain old JavaScript (non-Angular) form of calling a function when an element is clicked:

```
<span id="foo1" onclick="clicked(this)">...</span>
```

So the `this` argument to `clicked()` is the `span` object (`foo1`) that is clicked.

When this code is converted to AngularJS, we attempt to pass the same `this` object:

```
<span id="foo2" ng-click="clicked(this)">...</span>
```

Now, however, the argument passed to `clicked()` is an object, but it does not appear to have any relation to the `span` object.

So my questions are:

1. What is the value of `this` when passed to a function by `ng-click`?
2. What is the easiest way to retrieve the clicked object within the function, or pass it into the function?

Comment: You can pass `$event` into the function and use `$event.target`

Comment: I think `this` is `scope` but not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 1. When passing `this` as a parameter to a function in the `ng-click` directive, `this` will reference the current `$scope` object.
- 2. You could pass the [`$event` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) and then access the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)/[`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) properties to get a reference to the element.

  For instance [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv1ve5mm/):

  ```
  <button ng-click="click($event)">Click Me!</button>
  ```

  ```
  $scope.click = function (e) {
    e.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
  }
  ```